# Hive Buckets-understanding TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET X OUT OF Y)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Hi i am very much new to hive,i have gone through buckets concept in hadoop in action,but failed to understand the below lines.can any one help me on this?

```
SELECT avg(viewTime)
 FROM page_view TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 32);
```

The general syntax for TABLESAMPLE is
TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET x OUT OF y)

The sample size for the query is around 1/y. In addition, y needs to be a multiple or factor of the number of buckets specified for the table at table creation time. For example, if we change y to 16, the query becomes

```
SELECT avg(viewTime)
 FROM page_view TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 16);
```

Then the sample size includes approximately 1 out of every 16 users (as the bucket column is userid). The table still has 32 buckets, but Hive tries to satisfy this query by processing buckets 1 and 17 together. On the other hand, if y is specified to be 64, Hive will execute the query on half of the data in one bucket. The value of x is only used to select which bucket to use. Under truly random sampling its value shouldn’t matter.

Answer (score 15):

Which part of it don't you understand?

When you create the table and bucket it using the `clustered by` clause into 32 buckets (as an example), hive buckets your data into 32 buckets using deterministic hash functions. Then when you use `TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET x OUT OF y)`, hive divides your buckets into groups of **y** buckets and then picks the **x**'th bucket of each group. For example:

- If you use `TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 6 OUT OF 8)`, hive would divide your 32 buckets into groups of 8 buckets resulting in 4 groups of 8 buckets and then picks the 6th bucket of each group, hence picking the buckets 6, 14, 22, 30.
- If you use `TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 23 OUT OF 32)`, hive would divide your 32 buckets into groups of 32, resulting in only 1 group of 32 buckets, and then picks the 23rd bucket as your result.
- If you use `TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 3 OUT OF 64)`, hive would divide your 32 buckets into groups of 64 buckets, resulting in 1 group of 64 "half-bucket"s and then picks the half-bucket that corresponds to the 3rd full-bucket.