# Hive tablesampling and bucketing

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm new to Hive and facing some problem. I'm learning bucketing right now and my task is to create a Hive table that consists of 2 buckets, then put at least 5 records into that table. Well, that part is clear I think:

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename>(id INT,field2 STRING,field3 TINYINT) CLUSTERED BY(id) INTO 2 BUCKETS;
```

For populating the table I simply used insert into  values(...) statement. What I don't really know is the following - I have to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 2 ON id)
```

When I run it it returns 0 rows and I don't know why. I tried to look it up on the internet but didn't find exact answer. If I replace the id with an other field in the table it returns the rows in that bucket. So can someone explain it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I give you some tips for create and insert in bucketing tables.

**Bucketing** is an approach for improving `Hive` query performance.

**Bucketing** stores data in separate files, not separate subdirectories like partitioning.

It divides the data in an effectively random way, not in a predictable way like partitioning.

When records are inserted into a bucketed table, `Hive` computes hash codes of the values in the specified bucketing column and uses these hash codes to divide the records into buckets.

For this reason, **bucketing** is sometimes called **hash partitioning**.
The goal of **bucketing** is to distribute records evenly across a predefined number of buckets.

**Bucketing** can improve the performance of joins if all the joined tables are bucketed on the join key column.

For more on **bucketing**, see the page of the `Hive` Language Manual describing bucketed tables, at [BucketedTables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables?.)

As an example of **bucketing**:

Let us see how we can create Bucketed Tables in `Hive`.

Bucketed tables is nothing but Hash Partitioning in conventional databases.
We need to specify the `CLUSTERED BY` Clause as well as `INTO BUCKETS` to create Bucketed table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders_buck (
  order_id INT,
  order_date STRING,
  order_customer_id INT,
  order_status STRING
) CLUSTERED BY (order_id) INTO 8 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

DESCRIBE FORMATTED orders_buck;
```

Let us see how we can add data to bucketed tables.

Typically we use `INSERT` command to get data into bucketed tables, as source data might not match the criterial of our bucketed table.
If the data is in files, first we need to get data to stage and then insert into bucketed table.

We already have data in orders table, let us use to insert data into our bucketed table orders_buck
`hive.enforce.bucketing` should be set to true.

Here is the example of inserting data into bucketed table from regular managed or external table.

```sql
SET hive.enforce.bucketing;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;

INSERT INTO orders_buck
SELECT * FROM orders;

-- check out into the directory of the bucketed table if the 
-- number of files is equal to number of buckets

dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/training_retail.db/orders_buck;

SELECT * FROM orders_buck TABLESAMPLE(BUCKET 1 OUT OF 2 ON order_id);

-- In my case this query works perfectly well
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. For bucket 1 out of 2  I got the results but for bucket 2 out of 2 it fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 1. Is it normal or there's something I don't know?

Comment: to understand how buckets are working follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781869/hive-buckets-understanding-tablesamplebucket-x-out-of-y . I think it answers your question.